# sqlmodel: filter by null

Tags: python, filter, null, sqlmodel

Referring to the filtering examples here: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/where/#filter-rows-using-where-with-sqlmodel, how do I fetch all heroes whose age is null.

I need the equivalent of:

```
select * from hero where age is null
```

This works:

```
select(Hero).where(Hero.age != None)
```

but, IDE complains `PEP 8: E711 comparison to None should be 'if cond is not None:'`

So I changed it to:

```
select(Hero).where(Hero.age is None)
```

but, it does not work as intended causing an incorrect SQL to generate:

```
SELECT * FROM hero WHERE 0 = 1
```

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql.operators import is_


stmt = select(Hero).where(is_(Hero.age, None))
result = session.exec(stmt)
```